# set_option: Invalid argument when setting option boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group inside lambda

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-asio, multicast

This code is intended to receive UDP multicast messages using Boost.Asio. A Boost system_error exception is thrown by the code below when the second set_option() call inside receiver's constructor is made (to join the multicast group). The complaint is "Invalid argument". This seems to be related to the fact that the constructor occurs inside a lambda defined inside IO::doIO(), because using a member for the std::thread with identical functionality (IO::threadFunc()) instead results in the expected behavior (no exceptions thrown).

Why is this, and how can I fix it so that I may use a lambda?

```
//g++ -std=c++11 doesntWork.cc -lboost_system -lpthread

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class IO
{
public:
   class receiver
   {
   public:
      receiver(
         boost::asio::io_service         &io_service,
         const boost::asio::ip::address  &multicast_address,
         const unsigned short             portNumber) : _socket(io_service)
      {
         const boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(
            boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0"), portNumber);

         _socket.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
         _socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
         _socket.bind(listen_endpoint);
std::cerr << " About to set option join_group" << std::endl;
         _socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(
            multicast_address));

         _socket.async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(_data),
            _sender_endpoint,
            boost::bind(&receiver::handle_receive_from, this,
               boost::asio::placeholders::error,
               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
      }

   private:
      void handle_receive_from(
         const boost::system::error_code &error,
         const size_t                     bytes_recvd)
      {
         if (!error)
         {
            for(const auto &c : _data)
               std::cout << c;
            std::cout << std::endl;
         }
      }

   private:
      boost::asio::ip::udp::socket   _socket;
      boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint _sender_endpoint;
      std::vector<unsigned char> _data;
   }; // receiver class


   void doIO()
   {
      const boost::asio::ip::address multicast_address =
         boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("235.0.0.1");

      const unsigned short portNumber = 9999;

//       _io_service_thread = std::thread(
//          &IO::threadFunc, this, multicast_address, portNumber);

      _io_service_thread = std::thread([&, this]{
         try {
            // Construct an asynchronous receiver
            receiver r(_io_service, multicast_address, portNumber);

            // Now run the IO service
            _io_service.run();
         }
         catch(const boost::system::system_error &e)
         {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            throw e; //std::terminate()
         }
      });
   }

   void threadFunc(
      const boost::asio::ip::address &multicast_address,
      const unsigned short portNumber)
   {
      try {
         // Construct an asynchronous receiver
         receiver r(_io_service, multicast_address, portNumber);

         // Now run the IO service
         _io_service.run();
      }
      catch(const boost::system::system_error &e)
      {
         std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
         throw e; //std::terminate()
      }
   }

private:
   boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
   std::thread             _io_service_thread;
}; // IO class

int main()
{
   IO io;
   io.doIO();

   std::cout << "IO Service is running" << std::endl;

   sleep(9999);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a race condition that can result in dangling references being accessed, invoking undefined behavior.  The lambda capture-list is capturing the automatic variables, `multicast_address` and `portNumber`, by reference.  However, the lifetime of these objects may end before their usage within `_io_service_thread`:

```cpp
void doIO()
{
  const boost::asio::ip::address multicast_address = /* ... */;
  const unsigned short portNumber = /* ... */;

  _io_service_thread = std::thread([&, this] {
    // multicast_address and portNumber's lifetime may have already ended.
    receiver r(_io_service, multicast_address, portNumber);
    // ...
  });
} // multicast_address and portNumber are destroyed.
```

To resolve this, consider capturing by value so that the thread operates on copies whose lifetimes will remain valid until the end of the thread.  Change:

```cpp
std::thread([&, this] { /* ... */ }
```

to:

```cpp
std::thread([=] { /* ... */ }
```

This issue does not present itself when `std::thread` is constructed with the function and all its arguments, as the `std::thread` constructor will copy/move all provided arguments into thread-accessible storage.

Also, be aware of the destruction of the `_io_service_thread` object will invoke `std::terminate()` if it is still joinable within `IO`'s destructor.  To avoid this behavior, consider explicitly joining the `_io_service_thread` from the main thread.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.
The actual code does include a joinable() check and a join() in the IO class' destructor.